# HIghcharts 4 solid gauge max value

Tags: highcharts, max, gauge

I'm trying to display a solid gauge with a "strange" max value, that is 96 (hours).
I'read that max and min value are elaborated by highcharts to set ticks, ranges etc but I don't understand why I can't display such a value or even other rounded values like 90 below 100.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you creating your chart? We cant answer that without code.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo (i.e on the jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be that the chart is generating a default tick interval e.g. 10, which adds up to 100.

You may be able to get what you want by specifying a tickerInterval which divides into 96 (e.g. 8).

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 96,
        tickInterval:8,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vn4My/

Answer (score 2):

You can use any max value, only thing is you should **divide it by 1000** to get the **tickInterval** value, for example:

```
yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max:96,
        tickInterval:(96/1000),
    },
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NareshChennuri/whuu5qbt/

Comment: While dividing by 1000 works for lower values it drifts when using higher numbers. 708 becomes 710 and 480 becomes 481. Using `tickInterval:(max/256)` works even for the higher values

Answer (score 2):

To get the exact custom **max value :**

```
tickPositioner: function() {
  return [this.min, this.max];
},
min: 0,
max: 6924,
```

[refer this issue on github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5505#issuecomment-233558239)

Answer (score 1):

Try This I am also facing the same issue but I resolve that issue this solution may be useful for you.

```
 yAxis: {
  min: minData,
  max: maxData,
  tickPositions: [minData, maxData]
},
```

**Add tickPositions: [minData, maxData];**

pls check similar example [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jmrhq4an/)

Ref [reference click here](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38855#p134740)

I hope this is enough.

Thanks,

PVS